# How can I install applications (with apt-get) to an external disk?

Tags: apt, software-installation, external-hdd

I'm on a chromebook running Ubuntu inside a *chroot* via [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton). Thus, I have limited space. However, I have an external 32GB (extremely) high-speed SD Card. I'd like to install some of my larger programs via `apt-get` onto the external disk rather than internal SSD.

What's the best way to execute this? Most of my `apt-get` installations will stay in the internal drive so I shouldn't symlink the whole **/opt** directory. Is it safest and most efficient to install large packages via `apt-get` to the default directory and then cut the specific package's files and folders to the SD Card and symlink them back to the original location?

In addition, when I'm dealing with a mixture of software and files, what is the best format for my SD Card? I don't intend on sharing files with other devices/OS's via the SD Card often or ever.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to get apt-get to install to external memory. The individual symlink seems the best way to go, although a bit tedious(maybe you could write a bash script to do this for you?). As for the format, I would recommend ext4, but definitely not NTFS or FAT, those give bad performance and even sometimes read/write errors in linux.